Disable the check to install pending software updates upon shutdown
I have Ubuntu 22.04/ Jetson JP 6.0. Every time I shutdown, this check is enabled by default and I don't want my system to update automatically. I guess it has to do something with the gnome settings as I read here but I could be wrong. Does anyone know how to disable this check every time I shutdown?
I tried to change the GNOME setting mentioned in the link, but the tick still appears. Although, someone mentioned that the update functionality is disabled, but the tick still remains. I remain fearful in case it still updates.

